# Is there a way to limit the sound max volume?

Tags: audio, noise

I am wondering if there is a program that does that thing, I am not talking about lowering the volume, for example at night before I go to sleep I like putting a video on and listening to it, but I don't want the volume too high or too low, its really hard to balance it out when one guy is talking super loud and I can barely hear the other guy. too long didn't read: is there a program that can balance out all the loud noises and make them quieter or opposite.

thanks!

Comment: It isn't clear whether you are talking about some kind of noise cancellation, or a master volume control, or a volume limiter, or a volume compressor.  So your question is unclear.  To the extent it can be done with a built-in control or feature, this would be on-topic.  If you're requesting a software recommendation, that's off-topic.

Comment: Oh, volume limiter is the one, i just didn't know how to call that feature, ill try and search about that, thanks for helping

Comment: *"is there a program that can balance out all the loud noises and make them quieter or opposite."*  -- That's called a dynamic range compressor.  Loud sounds will be made softer, and soft sounds will be made louder.  E.G. Win7 MCE has a "night mode" audio setting (versus "theater" and "normal").

Comment: There is a loudness equalization setting in the Properties > Enhancements settings of your output device.

Comment: Use soundlock :- http://superuser.com/questions/897931/is-there-a-way-to-limit-the-sound-max-volume